# Improper integral convergence problem

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I need to show that this integral is convergent
$$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\arctan 2x -\arctan x}{x} dx$$
Maybe I should express $\arctan$ with one variable using $\tan (\alpha - \beta) = \ldots$

Anyway, I could use some help with this problem. It would be great to see some different solutions. Thanks

Comment: If all you need is to show the convergence: $\arctan 2x - \arctan x = \int_x^{2x} \arctan' t\,dt$. An easy estimate then yields the convergence.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/652899/85343) is a related problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$\arctan x=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\frac 1 x\right),\quad x>0$$
and 
$$\arctan\left(\frac 1 x\right)\sim_\infty \frac 1 x$$
so we find
$$\frac{\arctan 2x -\arctan x}{x}\sim_\infty\frac{ 1}{2 x^2}$$
so we deduce the desired result

Comment: Could you collaberate on how exactly you got the last equivalence.

Comment: You've got improper integrals down pat! +1

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray}
0\le \int_1^\infty\frac{\arctan2x-\arctan x}{x}\,dx&=&\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x}\left(\int_x^{2x}\frac{1}{1+t^2}\,dt\right)\,dx\\
&\le&\int_1^\infty\frac1x\left(\int_x^{2x}\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dt\right)\,dx\\
&=&\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx=\arctan x\Big|_1^\infty=\frac\pi2-\frac\pi4=\frac\pi4.
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

Note that beyond $x=1$, we have $\arctan(2x) - \arctan(x)$ to be a decreasing function. We hence have
\begin{align}
\int_{2^0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\arctan(2x)-\arctan(x)}{x} dx & < \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\arctan(2^{k+1})-\arctan(2^k)}{2^k} (2^{k+1} - 2^k)\\
& = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\arctan(2^{k+1})-\arctan(2^k)}{2^k} 2^k\\
& = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\arctan(2^{k+1})-\arctan(2^k) \right)\\
& = \dfrac{\pi}2 - \dfrac{\pi}4 = \dfrac{\pi}4
\end{align}
From $0$ to $1$, the integrand is bounded with a removable singularity at origin and hence we are done.