# Evaluate the improper integral

Tags: integration, trigonometry, improper-integrals

$$\int_0^\infty \dfrac{\arctan(ax)-\arctan(bx)}{x}~\mathrm{d}x$$
where $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers

I could not think of a way where to proceed from.
Please help!

Comment: Hint: $\;\arctan x-\arctan y=\arctan\frac{x-y}{1+xy}\;$ ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

$$\arctan{a x}-\arctan{b x} = x \int_b^a \frac{dy}{1+x^2 y^2}$$

Show that you can reverse the order of integration.  You then end up integrating

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^2 y^2} = \frac{\pi}{2 y}$$

I assume you can handle the rest.

Comment: @DonAntonio: thanks, and thanks.

Comment: I think so, maybe I was confusing myself too much by thinking about double integral! Thanks!

Comment: Very nice hint. +1

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}{%
\arctan\pars{ax}-\arctan\pars{bx} \over x}\,\dd x}:\ {\large ?}\,,
\qquad a, b\ \in {\mathbb R}\,,\quad a, b >0}$

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[#ffd,5px]{\int_{0}^{\infty}{%
\arctan\pars{ax}-\arctan\pars{bx} \over x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{x}\bracks{%
{a \over \pars{ax}^{2} + 1} -
{b \over \pars{bx}^{2} + 1}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x/a} \over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x
- \int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x/b} \over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\ln\pars{b \over a}\
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over x^{2} + 1}}
_{\ds{\pi \over 2}}\
=\
\bbox[10px,border:1px groove navy]{%
\half\,\pi\,\ln\pars{b \over a}} \\ &
\end{align}